# Changing object dimensions for different resolutions

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am a complete newbie at objective-C and have somehow managed to hack my way through making my first app. Well almost.

I built my app 4inch/retina and am now making it backward compatible to 3.5. I spent a couple hours messing with constraints and couldn't seem to get it working. My question - is it possible to change an object parameters according to phone resolution with code? Something like...

```
if(3.5 inch screen){
 object.height= 250px;
 object.x= 250px;
 object.y= 250px;
}else{
 object.height= 350px;
 object.x= 250px;
 object.y= 250px;
}
```

Thanks for any help.

[image: Bleh]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I use

```
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

int screen_h = self.view.frame.size.height;
int screen_w = self.view.frame.size.width;

if (screenBounds.size.height == 568) {
    // code for 4-inch screen
}
else {
    // code for 3.5-inch screen
}
```

Comment: Smick would this live in viewDidLoad ?

Comment: Yeah, it wont be changing if you segue to / from just needs to be done once when it loads.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong. You shouldn't change height based on the screen size.

Instead set fixed margins for top and bottom and make height variable.

Comment: Thanks Eimantas. Could you explain how this is done a bit better? Apologies, I am a noob.

Comment: Since you are doing this in storyboard, adjust layout constraints or autoresizing mask for the UIImageView.

Comment: Depending on your app, it can make perfect sense to have different heights depending on screen size. Not all apps are as simple as "more height -> more space for one field" - and one of the reasons iOS apps look so great compared to others is that their graphics are made exactly for certain screen sizes. So having some code depending on screen height like Smick writes in his answer cannot just be labeled "wrong", it depends on the screen.

Comment: TheEye - agreed. In my case I needed dynamic placement and sizing. Answer above turned out great.